Chrome/MacOS and Firefox/MacOS are able to render a string with glyphs from two fonts, but Chrome/iOS and Safari/Any are not
I want to declare a font-family property naming two fonts and have any glyphs not present in the first be rendered in the second. This works great in Chrome and Firefox on MacOS, but Safari/MacOS and both Chrome and Safari on iOS will only respect the first-listed font.
Minimal repro case:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Redacted+Script&family=Noto+Emoji&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            p {
                font-family: "Redacted Script", "Noto Emoji", sans-serif;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-style: normal;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello </p>
    </body>
</html>



The  smiley here should render in Noto Emoji, not whatever the browser's default emoji font is. That's what Chrome/MacOS and Firefox/MacOS do.
This is what I expect:

But in the bad cases I get this instead (the smiley is coming from Apple Emoji font, I think):

What am I doing wrong? Or is this mixing of fonts in a single string not supported in all browsers? Is there a workaround?

Could you make your code into a runnable snippet (<> in the editor) so it's easier to test on IOS devices?

Oh, that's nice! I did that :)

Your snippet is working fine for me on iPad IOS 16…. Safari. What version and device are you testing on?

…but on iPhone SE iOS 17… Safari I see the yellow emoji as you describe.

Well, that's curious about iPad/iOS 16.
On an iPhone 12 running iOS 17.4.1 I see the problem in both Safari and Chrome. On MacOS 14.3.1 both Chrome and Firefox do the right thing, but Safari does not.

In Safari it works if you change the order of families.
font-family: "Noto Emoji", "Redacted Script", cursive;

In fact, listing the emoji font first makes a lot more sense, because an emoji font is not going to attempt to render anything which is not an emoji, whereas a regular font is more likely to try to fill in any gaps in its repertoire by borrowing from other fonts.
A snippet to demonstrate – run this in Safari.


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Emoji:wght@300..700&family=Redacted+Script&display=swap');

body {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.p1 {
  font-family: "Redacted Script", "Noto Emoji", cursive;
}

.p2 {
  font-family: "Noto Emoji", "Redacted Script", cursive;
}
<p class="p1">hello </p>

<p class="p2">hello </p>




Oh, wow, what a simple but brilliant insight. The "real" version of this problem involves a base font and eight "special" fonts that have some of the symbols we require. We are subsetting all the eight special fonts, though, to just the symbols we need. It seems that if I list all those first and then the base font (which "feels" like the wrong way around) I get exactly the behavior I want in all the browsers I have access to. Thank you!
